# Swift4でタッチイベントをコードで動的に生成したい

Tags: swift, ios

iOSでは，ハードウェアが画面へのタッチを検出するとUIGestureRecognizerのイベントがコールされますが，こうした実際の物理的なタッチなしに，コード上でタッチしたように見せかけて（偽装する）イベントを送ることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

UIControlクラスの継承クラスであれば、こちらのAPIが利用できそうです
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618237-sendaction